# Converting numeric string to numeric in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want a method like to_numeric(str) which convert numeric string 'str' into its numeric form else return nil. By numeric form if string is in integer method should return integer and it string is in float it should return float.

I have tried with following code. It works fine but need better solution if possible.

```
def to_numeric(str)
  Integer(str)
rescue
  Float(str) if Float(str) rescue nil
end
```

One important thing I forgot to mention is "I don't know the type of my input".

My use case:

```
arr = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 4]
some_input = get_input_from_some_source

if arr.include?(to_numeric(some_input))
  # do something
end
```

Comment: try `to_i` method for string class http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_i

Comment: By 'numeric' I mean integer and float. I want to convert "1" or "1.34" to its numeric form.

Comment: `to_i` gives integer or float, particularly, an integer.

Comment: @sawa `"1.23".to_i` gives `1`, not `1.23`

Comment: @Stefan Yes, that's right. Exactly.

Comment: @budhram please explain why it is important to get the "correct" type? If it could be float, why not always convert to float?

Comment: @sawa I don't get the *"gives integer or float"* part, could you explain that?

Comment: @Stefan `to_i` returns an integer, so it returns an integer or a float. @nathanvda No, I responded to the second comment.

Comment: Euh @sawa, it returns an integer, so it returns an integer ;)

Comment: @qetzalcoatl that is correct. But not sure if that is the OP's case. Maybe he is just not proficient in ruby, just wants to convert strings to their numeric representation to store them in the database.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Ruby. Simply, the OP has not stated the question. All this mess stems from that. The OP only writes "numeric", and does not have a single mentioning of what class to expect under what circumstances. The OP is expecting the reader to guess all that and is being lazy.

Comment: @nathanvda: please check my updated question for my use case.

Comment: @budhram just use floats `[4].include? 4.0 #=> true`

Comment: @budhram: from your use-case, it seems like `myInput.to_f` would do the trick, but if it's your **precise** use case, then you may need to change it. Comparisons between `floats/doubles/..` is not always what you'd expect. The number `1.5` might not be possible to store exactly-like-it-is in a "numeric type". It might be `1.5000000001`. If after parsing the input you get `1.49999999`, you wouldn't find it in the array by simple `include?`.

Comment: @qetzalcoatl: Agreed with that. But I know the comparison source 'arr'(here) that it will either contain integer or floating point rounding off to 2. Then, can in such case i can round off input to 2 and could use method to_numeric. What you suggest?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`BigDecimal#frac`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-frac) to achieve what you want

```
require 'bigdecimal'

def to_numeric(anything)
  num = BigDecimal.new(anything.to_s)
  if num.frac == 0
    num.to_i
  else
    num.to_f
  end
end
```

It can handle

```
#floats
to_numeric(2.3) #=> 2.3

#rationals
to_numeric(0.2E-4) #=> 2.0e-05

#integers
to_numeric(1) #=> 1

#big decimals
to_numeric(BigDecimal.new("2"))
```

And floats, rationals and integers in form of strings, too

Comment: +1 This solution leaves the actual conversion to a ruby library and is easy to read (=maintain) (although it can only handle strings as input)

Comment: @tessi Now it can take anything responding to `#to_s` as input :)

Comment: Feel da Beat! Nice solution! But keep in mind the following two cases aren't really handled by the proposed solution nicely: [CASE-1] to_numeric(1.0000000000000001) / 2
=> 0, while if we omit to_numeric call then we'll get different result: 1.0000000000000001 / 2
=> 0.5      [CASE-2] to_numeric(1.0)
=> 1, so again if we're to use "to_numeric()" to distill stream of strings that represent numbers, then those two cases can bite us in our arse ;)  ps: It wasn't me downvoting : )

Comment: I'll just leave this here: `Integer('0010') => 8`

Answer (score 4):

Convert it to `Float` using [String#to_f](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_f) method. Since ruby using [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) you may not care if it can be an `Integer`.

If it looks like a numeric, swims like a numeric and quacks like a numeric, then it probably is a numeric.

But be aware! `to_f` does not throw any exceptions:

```
"foobar".to_f # => 0
```

Comment: "1.2".to_f   # 1.2 OK. But "1".to_f   # 1.0 No Ok. I need converter which will will "1.2"  to 1.2  and "1" to 1.

Comment: and if you want to specifically have Integer, then use `"123".to_i`

Comment: @user2422869: actually, even in Ruby you should "care about integers". The math operators like / work differently on them, so having 2 / 3 is not the same as 2.0 / 3.0, and having everything in floats is not always the right way :) I'm not saying your answer is wrong. I just say you have to care.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl yes, thanks. And I am pretty sure that float operations are slower.

Answer (score 3):

If you really insist to differentiate between Integer and Floats, then you can implement `to_numeric` like this:

```
def to_numeric(thing)
  return thing.to_s.to_i if thing.to_s == thing.to_s.to_i.to_s  
  return thing.to_s.to_f if thing.to_s == thing.to_s.to_f.to_s  
  thing
end
```

It converts an object to an integer, if its string representation looks like an integer (same with float), or returns the unchanged thing if not:

```
['1', '1.5', 'foo', :bar, '2', '2.5', File].map {|obj| to_numeric obj}
# => [1, 1.5, "foo", :bar, 2, 2.5, File]
```

Comment: This looks nice answer to my use case. Thanks.

Comment: I need to reconsider this solution as to_numeric("0.2E-4") is returning "0.2E-4"(string). Found that "0.2E-4".to_s.to_f.to_s is returning "2.0e-05" (Weird).

Comment: Sad, but true :) I think @beat-richarts's solution handles this better.

Comment: Yes. Have you tried my solution. It works for all cases except BigDecimal. :)

Comment: This approach doesn't work for strings such as 0.000001 where the to_s function may return "1.0e-05". The expression s == s.to_f.to_s also makes assumptions about floating point precision which may  be incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some options:

1. Use floats for comparison:

   ```
   arr = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 4]
   arr.include? "4.0".to_f #=> true
   ```
2. Use strings for comparison:

   ```
   arr = %w(1 1.5 2 2.5 4)
   arr.include? "4" #=> true
   ```
3. Use `eval` for conversion:

   ```
   eval("4.0") #=> 4.0
   eval("4")   #=> 4
   ```

   But you have to be very careful when using `eval`, see @tessi's comment.

Comment: The OP gets his input from the `get_input_from_some_source`. This does *not* sound like a good input for `eval`.

Comment: Yes, you would have to check the input before passing it to eval. A simple `Regexp` should do the trick.

Comment: Right, but one should be careful suggesting `eval`. A "simple regexp" like `/^\d*\.?\d*$/` might still be harmful for a string like `"42\nFile.delete(__FILE__)"`. `eval` is a valid solution (just use `\A` and `\z` in the regexp) but is not a good recommendation for beginners.

Comment: Of course and I don't think it's necessary to use `eval` here, I've just added it as an example to convert a `String` to either `Float` or `Integer` (the OP's original question).

Comment: Eval was the perfect solution for my code golf challenge, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```rb
def to_numeric(str)
  str.include?(".") ? str.to_f : str.to_i
end
```

Comment: It wouldn't work with Strings containing "e" or "E" like "5e3". Or, for an original String s="5 is ok.",  your method converts it to a Float, 5.0.